# Autologin on StackExchange sites didn't work

Tags: bug, auto-login

After the `read-only` period yesterday the autologin fails to login on StackExchange network sites.

**OS:** Windows 8.1

**Browser:** Google Chrome 37.0.2062.76 (x64)